# Prove the third isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove the third Isomorphism theorem as stated below

Theorem. Let $G$ be a group, $K$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$ with $K⊆N$. Then $$(G⁄K)⁄(N⁄K)≅G⁄N.$$

I look up for some answered on google, but I don't understand any of those. I wonder if any one can show me this proof step by step. I don't want to get it done, I want to understand why this theorem is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\phi(gK)=gN$ is a (well-defined) group homomorphism, and that its kernel is $N/K$. Then apply an (earlier) isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I know, @rschwieb . After some time our neurons seem to have a life of their own. :)

Comment: Same solution a minute earlier, and yet no credit :( I guess "money attracts money," as they say...

Comment: Well, I'm cuter...:) I think people loves seeing different steps in a solution, and the more detailed the answer the better received it usually is. The minute (or even several good minutes) more or less are practically irrelevant, in particular because since a couple of weeks ago I noticed the site's system no longer writes down the answers up-to-down according as when they were posted, and not even according to the upvotes. It seems to be pretty irregular now, so first answer seen first answer loved...or something like that.

Comment: @DonAntonio ... but we have the same details! It *is* possible you are just cuter...

Comment: Well @rschwieb, and I *didn't want to break these news to you this suddenly and abruptly*, then it *must* be the "cuter" part kicking in...:P)

Comment: @DonAntonio I will have to develop a charming accent, and then a method to work it into my answers, and then maybe I'll be able to compete with your lovability.

Comment: ...and don't forget many typos here and there: that usually tenderizes upvoters' hearts.

Comment: Both of you are cute :D and I appreciate seeing different steps in solution. Just like I said, I really want to understand this problem so that I can be ready for final exam. I know that $(G/K)/(N/K)=$ ${aK|a in G}$. But should we define the function $ϕ:(G/K)/(N/K)→G/N$, instead of just $ϕ:G/K→G/N$. Or it doesn't matter because they are both collection of  left cosets of K.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif The easy way to do it is to avoid work and just define $\phi:G/K\to G/N$, and then *let the first isomorphism theorem* assert that there exists an isomorphism between $(G/K)/(N/K)\to G/N$. There is no need to work out exactly what it is, although you could if you wanted to.

Comment: oh, I forgot the transitive property of isomorphism, thank you, rchwieb

Comment: There you go, @rschwieb ! Now Diane's accepted your answer to balance things (and my heart bleeds...). :)

Comment: @DonAntonio To add irony to injury, I upvoted your answer as well :)

Comment: And now I upvoted yours: you won't be nicer than I am!

Comment: I wonder how come we haven't yet been kicked out of this site for being such a pain...

Answer (score 7):

Hints: define

$$\phi: G/K\;\to\; G/N\;,\;\;\phi(gK):=gN$$

(1) Prove $\,\phi\,$ is well a defined, onto homomorphism

2) Find $\,\ker\phi\,$

(3) Apply the first isomorphism theorem